# JSON infer class type based on Dictionary key

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I would like to deserialize a `Dictionary<string, AbstractDataObject>`. `AbstractDataObject` is an abstract class which `SomeClass1` and `SomeClass2` inherit from. The key value of the dictionary (a string) is the name of the class:

```
{
  "StoredData": {
    "SomeClass1": {
      "Foo": "Test"
    },
    "SomeClass2": {
      "Bar": 123
    }
  }
}
```

The classes look like following (simplified):

```
public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, AbstractDataObject> StoredData { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractDataObject
{
}

public class SomeClass1 : AbstractDataObject 
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass2 : AbstractDataObject
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

How can I tell Json.NET to infer the class type based on the Dictionary key? I've looked around but I'm unsure where to start implementing this functionality

Comment: Using Type names is dangerous, since it defeats the typical purpose of Serialization, which is to allow for fully decoupled Client/Server. Is there a way you can design it such that there is an explicit contract?

Comment: @SilasReinagel What do you mean by explicit contract?

Comment: For example, use concrete data objects in your client code, for specific remote calls.

Comment: @SilasReinagel Oh, that would require a complete rewrite of my current code base though :(  Is there a way to still achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: I don't believe that functionality is included in Json.NET. You would have to create a layer yourself to determine the type before Deserializing. It's not very hard to do, but might cause you some headaches further into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a custom `JsonConverter` to handle this:

```
public class CustomDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, AbstractDataObject>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, AbstractDataObject>();
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
        {
            switch (prop.Name)
            {
                case "SomeClass1":
                    dict.Add("SomeClass1", prop.Value.ToObject<SomeClass1>(serializer));
                    break;

                case "SomeClass2":
                    dict.Add("SomeClass2", prop.Value.ToObject<SomeClass2>(serializer));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, new CustomDictionaryConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ba4wB6